# Test Execution Result History

Tags: apex, unit-test

Is there a history of test execution available for querying after a test is run? In the Salesforce Classic Apex Test page you can obviously see some recent tests, and their results individually. However, if you are working in a really large project (800+ classes), you will end up with lots and lots of tests, and from what I've seen, if you run every test in the organization, it won't take long for the page to clear the logs, and you won't be able to see, say, the tests that failed.

This is a pretty annoying issue for me at the moment, because in between 100 classes, when 10 or so fail, they are split between the other 90 classes. When I take some time to take a note of the name of those classes, the page is cleared automatically, and I'm forced to run the tests again to see which ones failed.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this similar issue when multiple developers running the tests and clearing the test results.

Then I started using Developer Console for running tests. Once tests are run, test tab will show the test run and the test methods under it.

[image]

If you just want to rerun the failed tests you can do so by going to Test -> Rerun Failed Tests

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: It really does. Since by running the failed tests I can also see their names, and notify the correct people. Thank you. :) That was quick!